# Site.createExternalUser() method is failing for particular account

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, customer-community

Issue we are currently having is that we found out that the only Contacts that are failing for one  Account.

This Account has **100000 Contacts associated**.

Is it possible that the `Site.createExternalUser()` method is failing due to the amount of Contacts associated to this Account? Is there some sort of limit?

The error that comes inside the debug log is account owner has no role assigned. Is the role of the account causing that.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use this method you must make sure the Account Owner is assigned to a role hierarchy.

You need to set the "Role" field on the "User Detail Screen" for the Owner of the failing account.

Comment: The role is already provided to the user , There are two fields partner and customer role . Is there anything needs to be checked

Comment: @cloudlover Are you sure the OWNER of the account is assigned to a role?   Can you add screenshots for confirmation (one of the account owner field and one of the user detail)?